Identifying 10-pin power IC
Unfortunately I can't find the following component on the internet. No matter what I type, I can't find anything.
5A TI 51240
3C TI 51240?
The two ICs are broken on both boards. It happened when the plus and minus were swapped.
The board runs at 12 V or 24 V.
Boat plotter


Please provide package dimesions and pin pitch

The pinout looks similar to the TPS54240, perhaps it's a 54240 and the printing has rubbed off the second digit?

This looks correct +1, compare the image at LCSC. I suspect the markings were maybe more exploded off than rubbed off.

You could be right!
Thank you very much :)

@Serhudi Please accept this answer (by clicking on the checkmark to its left) in order to indicate you think it is correct.
